How to create Enterprise on your existing newly created IBM-Cloud account?
Recently, I created a new IBM cloud Pay-As-You-Go account and I selected Enterprise as type when creating the account, it has been created.
However, when I go to "Enterprise" tab, to "Create" Organization, the button is not clickable and I am itself owner of the account, so it's not permission related issue.
Upon creating support case, I was told that it has to be contacted IBM Partner service(local sales team), which I find unreasonable since all other public cloud can create Enterprise account directly without partner support(local sales team).
Here's FAQ: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/secure-enterprise?topic=secure-enterprise-enterprise-faqs#enterprise-account-type
I don't see it has any kind of restriction on creation of Enterprise Account byself
Any advice?

Is your PAYGO account with a credit card or some type of voucher?

Credit card @data_henrik

I was told by IBM Support finally that if account is created in China, then Enterprise creation is not possible. I haven't seen such in documentation, so it is something new.
